# Why can't I connect using an older version of Tor?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

My college has one or two facilities enabled with WiFi. I've been provided with complete access to the Internet. A few websites were blocked by the router (say Twitter, YouTube, probably any site that's fun!). I was using Tor (v2.3) to access those sites. I used v2.3 because I like the Vidalia Panel, the details, logs, customization etc. are quite charming, until...

Last week, something terrible happened. Whenever I try to connect to the network, it's stuck here, at *"Establishing an encrypted directory connection"*.

[image]

Then, I tried using v3.6.3. It connects (within a few seconds) as usual. I'm able to browse those sites. So, what's the big deal? Why's there a conflict between both of these versions? I'm curious why this happened all of a sudden.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know why the connection failed in this case, but you should **always use the latest version of the Tor Browser Bundle**, as the older version may have security vulnerabilities.

If you miss Vidalia, then use the standalone Vidalia bundle together with the most recent version of the TBB (currently 3.6.**4**), as described here: https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#WhereDidVidaliaGo